# Does the underlying character set depend only on the C implementation?

Tags: c, ascii

Many texts warn that processing `char` values as integers isn't portable, e.g. assuming that the value of 'A' is 65 (as in ASCII).

But what determines whether this character set is ASCII (or an extended form), or some other character set? Is it determined by the operating system, or the compiler? I'm presuming that this isn't dependent on the hardware.

For example, could an Intel PC have a character set such as EBCDIC (in theory)? And could changing the `LANG` environment variable in Linux/Unix change the values of the basic character set for C programs (if then recompiled)?

(edit: I see now that the various non-Latin character sets in Linux all have the same basic ASCII codes, e.g. [KOI8-U](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI8-U) - I assumed that there were variations that had character sets not compatible with ASCII)

Comment: I think this is implementation defined.

Comment: The compiler decides. Of course, some decisions would make it such a compiler much less useful.

Comment: Sure, anything *could* happen. The real question is, *will* this ever happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard doesn't care about any of those details, as far as it's concerned there's only "the implementation".

In practice, hardware and OSes can both specify implementation details that C implementations on that platform are expected to use, or that they're *required* to use if they want to inter-operate with system functions (that is to say, code that is supplied with the OS or with the hardware). So we often say things like, "on Win32, `sizeof(void*) == 4`". This is a shorthand, though, since someone *could*, if they chose, write a C implementation that runs on 32 bit Windows and has a different pointer size. What we really mean is, "in the Win32 ABI, `sizeof(void*) == 4`, and C implementations running on Win32 that don't follow the Win32 ABI are excluded from consideration".

Implementations therefore can do whatever they like, provided they don't mind whether or not they can (for example) use dlls that follow the system's conventions. The character set can be defined however the writer of the compiler and standard libraries likes, subject only to what's in the standard.

That said, the values of character literals are compile-time constants. This tells you that the basic execution character set cannot change during runtime.

Furthermore, if it were to depend on an environment variable then it would be somebody's responsibility to ensure that the program was run with the same value that it was compiled with. This would be pretty user-unfriendly, but the standard doesn't actually *forbid* someone from writing a C implementation with peculiar restrictions on how programs are run.

Comment: My question about the environment variable was rather this - assuming that Linux for instance has character sets available that aren't ASCII based (via the LANG variable), if you compiled a program with an ASCII character set, and then again with a non-ASCII character set in the same OS, would you get different constants?

Comment: @teppic: if you had a compiler that lets you vary the character set then yes, you'd get different values. I wouldn't be all that surprised if gcc has an EBCDIC option somewhere. The point is that if you *ran* the program with the non-ASCII character set against a standard library that uses ASCII, then for example `isspace` might not work.

Comment: Ok. I guess I'm wondering whether you could end up with the same OS producing (by default) different codes depending on locale settings. e.g. if someone is running Linux with a locale that isn't compatible with ASCII, whether the implementation would just use ASCII values anyway, or if code that depended on ASCII values would break.

Comment: @teppic: there are no Linux locales that aren't compatible with ASCII, so the issue doesn't arise. The extended execution character set can change, though (and the multi-byte encoding). If you have strings embedded in your code in the "wrong" encoding then they'll misbehave when you change locale. But the basic character set is a binary compatibility issue, changing that is like trying to change the size of `int` or the signed-ness of `char` (which gcc does have an option for, btw). It becomes a "different" C implementation.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Ah thanks. I didn't realise that all Linux characters sets were compatible with ASCII (which would make sense if system libraries depended on it). I assume this is true for basically any Unix implementation that uses an ASCII-compatible character set.

Comment: @teppic: strictly speaking, there are some characters in ASCII that aren't in the C basic set. Control characters and suchlike. I suppose that the meanings of those code points could change with locale (how they're displayed on screen, the result of calling `isspace` with those values), and I'm not absolutely certain that they don't. What can't change with locale is e.g. the result of calling `isspace('\t')`. And the value of `'\t'` itself can't change with locale because it's a constant expression.

Comment: so if I'm understanding this, although many variations are possible in theory, any character set on a particular OS/hardware platform is always going to be compatible with the rest on that platform for the basic C set, because the programs (and the C toolchain) all need to agree on those values to have any real compatibility with each other. Thus in practice you're never going to run into problems (such as what 'A' means) on a platform by changing the charset.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard says this:

**§5.2.1/1 in C99**

> Two sets of characters and their associated collating sequences shall be defined: the set in
>   which source files are written (the source character set), and the set interpreted in the
>   execution environment (the execution character set). Each set is further divided into a
>   basic character set, whose contents are given by this subclause, and a set of zero or more
>   locale-specific members (which are not members of the basic character set) called
>   extended characters. The combined set is also called the extended character set. The
>   values of the members of the **execution character set are implementation-defined**.

At startup the compiler must use the C locale, it will only pick up the OS's locale, when `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` is called.

Comment: What does this say in regard to the question, about whether the character set depends on the C implementation?

Comment: @EricPostpischil "implementation defined" means it depends on the implementation.

Comment: What I am asking is why mentioning the OS’s locale is relevant. Are you trying to say that switching to the OS’s locale can change the C implementation’s definition of the character set? Then I would disagree; the OS’s locale is part of the implementation. If you are merely saying that the locale can be changed but not saying that does change’s the implementation’s definition of the character set, then I do not see the point; speaking about the locale has not provided any information related to the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Whether Tony's saying it or not, yes, changing the locale can change the character set, what characters are valid, how they're interpreted, etc.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Whether the character set changes is not the question. The question is whether the C implementation determines the character set (including changes) or something else affects it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Both, to varying degrees. If you use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` (or variants that affect only the character set) you're specifically asking for whatever locale the user has requested, which (usually) depends on how they've configured the OS.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Then this is where I would disagree. The OS is **not** outside the implementation. It is part of the implementation. The fact that a character set depends on the OS does not imply the character set is not completely defined by the implementation, so the final sentence in this answer is at best irrelevant and may be misleading.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'd suggest you reread the question. He's specifically asking about the compiler vs. the OS vs. (at least by implication) the hardware -- all of which could be considered part of the implementation. By lumping them all together, you're just ignoring the question.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I was indeed reading the question as stated in the title, which specifically asks about the C implementation. Nonetheless, I judge this answer to be unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler clearly determines which source and execution character set is used, since cross-compilation can occur (eg. compiling code for an IBM mainframe that uses EBCDIC on your Linux box that uses ASCII).

Comment: So the compiler determines that all x86 Linux code uses ASCII, and that's set in the implementation? What about an x86 Linux box using a character set that isn't ASCII based?

Comment: @teppic "*So the compiler determines that all x86 Linux code uses ASCII, and that's set in the implementation?*" I didn't say that; I was giving an example. Which compiler are you referring to? "*What about an x86 Linux box using a character set that isn't ASCII based?*" I presume this configuration wouldn't have any use for code that uses the ASCII character set, without any translation mechanism.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue , so you are implying you can compile code of an IBM that uses EBCDIC , on a x86 linux ?

Comment: @BarathBushan Such a compiler would be a conformant C translator. Sure.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue , ya i figured , so in short , even though there is system specific encoding , all systems do support ASCII , in its native form without any customizations

Comment: @BarathBushan: What is your basis for the claim that all systems support ASCII?

Comment: @BarathBushan: all compilers are *permitted* to support ASCII as a compilation option. That doesn't mean they're required to or that all non-ASCII systems actually have a compiler that does so. Not that non-ASCII systems often crop up, of course.

Comment: @EricPostpischil , read my comment properly , am not claiming anything , i am "in short" , trying to confirm if what lvalue is saying , is what i think it to be

Comment: @BarathBushan: Have you studied OpenSSL? http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-23/openssl/crypto/ebcdic.c

Comment: @SteveJessop , yes the point i was trying to make was , even if systems had their own implementation , they do give an option to encode in ASCII , which you clarified just now

Comment: @modifiablelvalue will be glad to have a look at it

Comment: @BarathBushan: I do not see an interpretation of your text “all systems do support ASCII” as anything other than a claim that all systems support ASCII. The text does not appear to be in a conditional clause.

Comment: @BarathBushan Perhaps you should find the part of the C standard that talks about source and execution character sets, and read it...

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I meant what i meant ,i don't have to use any clauses , am making a comment , not writing a magazine :)

Comment: @modifiablelvalue +1 for your answer , the link supports your answer , that ebcdic systems do have a way to implement ascii