# Behavior of extended bytes/characters in C/POSIX locale

Tags: c, character-encoding, posix, locale

C and POSIX both require only a very limited set of characters be present in the C/POSIX locale, but allow additional characters to exist. This leaves a great deal of freedom to the implementation; for instance, supporting all of Unicode (as UTF-8) in the C locale is conforming behavior. However, most historical implementations treat the C locale as having an "8-bit-clean" single-byte character encoding, either ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) or a sort of "abstract 8-bit character set" where the non-ASCII bytes are abstract characters with no particular identity. (However, in the latter case, if the compiler defines `__STDC_ISO_10646__`, they normatively correspond to Unicode characters, usually the Latin-1 range.)

Another conforming option that seems much less popular is to treat all non-ASCII bytes as non-characters, i.e. respond to them with an `EILSEQ` error.

What I'm interested in knowing is whether there are implementations which take this or any other unusual options in implementing the C locale. Are there implementations where attempting to convert "high bytes" in the C locale results in `EILSEQ` or anything other than treating them as (abstract or Latin-1) single-byte characters or UTF-8?

Comment: so the question is, given two options given by the standard, whether the less popular version is implemented anywhere? Also I think you should be a lot more careful in your wording: glyph, character and code point are different idea, even though they can overlap.

Comment: I don't see there being "two options", rather a whole range of options. All that's required by POSIX is that the C/POSIX locale contain the specified set of single-byte characters. Whether any other characters exist at all in this locale is unspecified (XBD 7.2 paragraph 2). The majority of implementations define each remaining byte as being a single-byte character (often treating them as the Latin-1 characters), but there is no requirement to do this. They could also be used in a multi-byte encoding (like UTF-8 or a legacy CJK DBCS) or not defined as characters at all (EILSEQ).

Comment: XBD 7.2 is actually a bit confusing in this regard. The first paragraph ("The behavior of standard utilities and functions in the POSIX locale shall be as if the locale was defined via the localedef utility with input data from the POSIX locale tables in Locale Definition.") makes it sound like EILSEQ is required for bytes not explicitly defined as characters in the tables, but this does not match historical behavior, and the second paragraph turns around and  makes the behavior explicitly unspecified.

Comment: Anyway, I'm just looking for examples of implementations that don't match the most popular historic behavior of treating each byte as a single-byte character in the C/POSIX locale.

Answer (score 11):

From your comment to the previous answer:

> The ways in which the assumption could be wrong are basically that bytes outside the portable character set could be illegal non-character bytes (EILSEQ) or make up some multibyte encoding (UTF-8 or a stateless legacy CJK encoding)

[Here](http://man.cat-v.org/plan_9/6/utf) you can find one example.

Plan 9 only supports the "C" locale. As you can see in [utf.c](http://swtch.com/usr/local/plan9/src/cmd/tcs/utf.c) and [rune.c](http://swtch.com/usr/local/plan9/src/lib9/utf/rune.c), when it find a rune outside the portable characters, it simply handles it as a character from a different encoding.

Another candidates could be [Minix](https://github.com/minix3/minix/blob/master/lib/libc/citrus/citrus_none.c) and the [*BSD family](http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/src/lib/libc/citrus/citrus_none.c) (as far as they use [citrus](http://citrus.bsdclub.org/)). In the Minix source code I've also found the [file command](https://github.com/minix3/minix/blob/master/external/bsd/file/dist/src/encoding.c#l84) looking for new encoding when the character size is not 8bit.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question. I'm not going to accept this answer (though I might give you the bounty and then open a new one if nobody else comes up with a better answer) since Plan 9 does not claim or attempt to conform to POSIX, and it's already the canonical example of a pure UTF-8 system. I'm really looking for some examples that attempt to be POSIX systems.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the deadline for assigning the bounty, but since I upvoted your answer it seems to have automatically been assigned half the bounty value.

Comment: @R.. btw... can I ask "why"?

Comment: See the thread "[1003.1(2008)/Issue 7 0000663]: Specification of str[n]casecmp is ambiguous" on http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general. The aim is to show diversity of historical practice as a reason not to make a change in the standard that precludes UTF-8-only implementations.

Comment: Funny! I vote for that (pro UTF-8, I mean). :-) I'm just not sure that the citrus link are historical: they are still there. BTW, [this](http://www.undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20100729233638) could be useful too.

Comment: Still the best answer so far, so you get the second bounty too. :-)

Comment: I don't follow how you think BSD or Minix are examples. Can you elaborate?

Comment: As of now, the third bounty is over and your answer is still the only one that answers the question at all. I'd like to know what you mean about BSD/Minix still, but I'm awarding the bounty now so it doesn't get cut in half when the time-to-award expires. I may or may not open another one...

Comment: Many parts of the Minix's source code come from BSD. Both the linked BSD and Minix use the citrus library, that as far as I can see from the linked source code (related to the "C" locale), returns EINSEQ on unexpected sequences (see for example [_citrus_NONE_ctype_wcrtomb](https://github.com/minix3/minix/blob/master/lib/libc/citrus/citrus_none.c#L228) ).

Comment: The code you linked to is treating the C locale as 8-bit. `mbtowc` is converting each byte to a wide character, and `wcrtomb` is converting the range 0..255 back to bytes. `EILSEQ` is only given for wide character values outside the 8-bit range, not anything outside the 7-bit range.

Answer (score 5):

Amusingly, I just found that the most widely-used implementation, glibc, is an example of what I'm looking for. Consider this simple program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        wchar_t wc = 0;
        int n = mbtowc(&wc, "\x80", 1);
        printf("%d %.4x\n", n, (int)wc);
}
```

On glibc, it prints `-1 0000`. If the byte 0x80 were an extended character in the implementation's C/POSIX locale, it would print 1 followed by some nonzero character number.

Thus, the "common knowledge" that the C/POSIX locale is "8-bit-clean" on glibc is simply false. What's going on is that there's a gross inconsistency; despite the fact that all the standard utilities, regular expression matching, etc. are specified to operate on (multibyte) characters as if read by `mbrtowc`, the implementations of these utilities/functions are taking a shortcut when they see `MB_CUR_MAX==1` or `LC_CTYPE` containing `"C"` (or similar) and reading `char` values directly instead of processing input with `mbrtowc` or similar. This is leading to an inconsistency between the specified behavior (which, as their implementation of the C/POSIX locale is defined, would have to treat high bytes as illegal sequences) and the implementation behavior (which is bypassing the locale system entirely).

With all that said, I am still looking for other implementations with the properties requested in the question.

Comment: +1 Quite incredible. In the **[mbtowc](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/mbtowc.c)** source code you can find a worrisome warning, that intimate to use **[mbrtowc](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=wcsmbs/mbrtowc.c)** instead. mbrtowc however is sensible to the locale: what's wrong with it? By using this second function, utilities do not bypass the locale... do they?

Comment: I just used `mbtowc` rather than `mbrtowc` because it made the example simpler, but either can be used. Except in a locale with stateful encoding, as long as you always pass large enough `n` that a whole character can be read, `mbrtowc` is safe to use. It's actually required by POSIX to be thread-safe too. By the way, the C/POSIX locale is required by POSIX to be stateless (and FYI, UTF-8 is stateless in this definition).

Comment: As for "bypassing the locale", neither `mbrtowc` nor `mbtowc` bypasses it. What's going on is that coreutils (and regex/fnmatch/glob code, etc.) are skipping calling `mbtowc` or `mbrtowc` when `MB_CUR_MAX==1` or when the locale is `"C"` (not sure which), and just processing bytes manually. This is what "ignoring the locale" means, at least to me.

Answer (score 4):

> "What I'm interested in knowing is whether there are implementations which take this or any other unusual options in implementing the C locale."

This question is very difficult to answer because it mixes the "C Locale", which I'm assuming refers to the C Standard limited character set mentioned above, with "other unusual options", which I'm assuming refers to how the specific implementation handles characters **outside** the (limited) C locale.  Every C Implementation must implement the C Locale; I don't think there's any *unusual options* surrounding that.

Let's assume for argument that the question is: "...unusual options in implementing **additional/extended characters beyond** the C locale."  Now this becomes an implementation-dependent question, and as you have already mentioned, it "leaves a great deal of freedom to the implementation."  So without knowing the target compiler/hardware, it would still be difficult to answer definitively.

Now the last part:

> "...attempting to convert "high bytes" in the C locale results in EILSEQ or anything other than treating them as (abstract or Latin-1) single-byte characters or UTF-8?"

Instead of converting high bytes while in the C Locale, you might be able to set the Locale in your program as in this SO Question: [Does the underlying character set depend only on the C implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251049/does-the-underlying-character-set-depend-only-on-the-c-implementation)

This way you can ensure that your characters will be treated in the Locale that you expect.

---

It is my understanding that the C Locale only concerns itself with the first 7-bits (of an 8-bit `char` type), based on the sources below:

- http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html
- http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/locale/

The terms "high bytes" and "Unicode" and "UTF-8" are in the class of multi-byte or wide-character encodings, and are very locale specific (and beyond the range of the minimal C Locale).  I'm not clear on how it would be possible to "convert high bytes" in the (pure) C Locale.  It's quite possible that implementations would pick a default (extended) locale if none was explicitly set (or pull it from the OS environment settings as stated in one of the links above).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post an answer. What I'm looking for though is not a way to get characters treated the way I want, but information on whether there are existing implementations with the properties I mentioned.

Comment: Did a bit more digging (see edited post above), and the more I look the more it seems to be in the "undefined behavior" category.  If you're going with multi-byte or wide-character encoding, it feels like you cannot rely on the C Locale for conversion...

Comment: Again, that's not what the question is about. The topic of the question is that some people, wrongly, assume that in the C/POSIX locale, each byte is a (single-byte) character, and I'm looking for evidence of implementations where this assumption is wrong in one or more ways.

Comment: The ways in which the assumption could be wrong are basically that bytes outside the portable character set could be illegal non-character bytes (`EILSEQ`) or make up some multibyte encoding (UTF-8 or a stateless legacy CJK encoding).

Comment: "assume that in the C/POSIX locale, each byte is a (single-byte) character" <-- I don't think this is a wrong/bad assumption, as the C Locale only defines 7-bits (of a single-byte) encoding scheme.  The bad assumption would come if you assume your input is in this type of encoding when it is not.  While in the C/POSIX Locale, I would think that your program would (blindly) process characters as single bytes, and only concern itself with the standard 7-bit ASCII w/i that byte.  (I'm sorry I wish I could be more help but I clearly don't understand the question.)

Answer (score 2):

The POSIX standard is quite clear in this regard.

The introduction to [character sets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap06.html) in POSIX.1-2017 says:

> 6.2 Character Encoding
>
> **The POSIX locale shall contain 256 single-byte characters** including the characters in Portable Character Set and Non-Portable Control Characters, which have the properties listed in LC_CTYPE. It is unspecified whether characters not listed in those two tables are classified as punct or cntrl, or neither. Other locales shall contain the characters in Portable Character Set and may contain any or all of the control characters identified in Non-Portable Control Characters; the presence, meaning, and representation of any additional characters are locale-specific.

(emphasis mine)

The page for [mbtowc()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mbtowc.html) says:

> The mbtowc() function shall fail if:
>
> [EILSEQ]
>  An invalid character sequence is detected. **In the POSIX locale an [EILSEQ] error cannot occur since all byte values are valid characters.**

Note that the POSIX locale is defined to be identical to the C locale.

So if an operating system conforms to POSIX, `mbtowc` is a no-op in the POSIX locale.  Characters 128–255 are passed through just as characters 0–127 are.  Implementations that operate differently are in violation of the standard.

Comment: The quoted text was written 2 years after the question was posted, in response to the same issue that this question was about. See http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=663#c2738. Still I think it's a useful answer since it shows what happened as a (very unfortunate) result, so please don't delete it.

Comment: BTW the claim that "`mbtowc` is a no-op" is still incorrect even with the changes made in the TC; the representations of characters outside the portable character set as `wchar_t` need not match their representations as `unsigned char`.